# Explain why the function given in parts is the solution of the differential equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Explain why the function given in parts,
$$y = \left\{\begin{align}\sqrt{25-x^2}\quad \text{for}\quad -5\lt x\lt 0\\-\sqrt{25-x^2}\quad \text{for}\quad 0\le x\lt 5\end{align}\right.$$

is the solution of the differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$ in $$(-5,5)$$

Comment: What does the graph of this function look like?  How will the slopes of the tangent lines (described by the differential equation) behave over that interval? (Does that "slope equation" seem familiar?)

Comment: To show that it is *a* solution it is enouhg to compute the derivative.

Comment: Solve the differential equation to see what's going on.

Comment: You can also write $y dy=-x dx$. Integration of bothe sides gives $y^2=-x^2+C$;then $y$. Do not forget that $y^2=something$ has two solutions (+ and -).

Comment: It isn't really necessary to solve anything -- the function and the differential equation have a straightforward geometrical interpretation.